# Missing tests in Cypress

Tags: visual-studio-code, cypress

Yesterday created folder "integration" through Visual Studio Code and added my tests in it, but Cypress do not see them. Then, moved tests to already exists folder "2-advanced-examples" and tests run fine.
Today I started Visual Studio Code and I see my tests in folder "2-advanced-examples" but missing them in same folder when start Cypress. Cypress removed my tests by unknown reason.
Any ideas about correct way to add my tests without to be removed again?
*Added screenshot from VSC and Cypress.
[image: My tests seen in VSC - "cookies_popup.cy.js", "test_login.cy.js"]
[image: Missing my tests in Cypress]

What I did for resolving: Restart Cypress, re-added tests to folder "2-advanced-examples".
Expected Cypress to display my tests.

Comment: So your tests were in `cypress/integration` and Cypress removed them? Or they were in `integration/`?

Comment: @agoff tests are in folder "2-advanced-examples" where is located default Cypress tests, if I check from VSC. But when I start Cypress by command "npx cypress open", I see no my tests in folder "2-advanced-examples" displayed  in Cypress itself. I added screenshots from a both sources.

Comment: Your screenshots make it unclear what is occurring. What is the relative path for the tests when they exist? What does your `cypress.config.{js|ts}` look like? Can you give an exact layout of your directories? The screenshots are less helpful than an actual text layout.